# Make invisible eShell(kiosk) window on startup

Tags: powershell, windows-iot-core-10, eshell

I want my file to start on eShell minimized or even better hidden.

Here is my code at this moment:

```
$ShellLauncherClass = [wmiclass]"\\localhost\root\standardcimv2\embedded:WESL_UserSetting"
$ShellLauncherClass.SetDefaultShell("D:\uvs\WinPOS\run.bat", 0)
$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($TRUE)
```

I can't find any kind of solution.

Edit:

Ok, so after a little bit research. This powershell just adds and enables eShell(Kiosk) function in windows that starts my run.bat. So if I add -WindowStyle Hidden into powershell, it just hides the powershell. The main thing that I need that this launched run.bat would be minimized on start or hidden

Comment: Found this VBScipt that helps to hide the window, but can i implement it to the existing powershell command that i have ?

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "D:\UVS\WinPOS\run.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing

Comment: Start powershell with `-WindowStyle Hidden` as first argument.

Comment: Ok, so after a little bit research. This powershell just adds and enables eShell(Kiosk) function in windows that starts my run.bat. So if I add -WindowStyle Hidden into powershell, it just hides the powershell. The main thing that I need that this launched run.bat would be minimized on start or hidden

Answer (score 0):

Ok so solution was best to implement the -WindowStyle -Minimized implemedted into the shell script. Thank you Santiago for the answer ! Didn't get it in the first time what you been suggesting me.

Full code:

`$ShellLauncherClass = [wmiclass]"\localhost\root\standardcimv2\embedded:WESL_UserSetting"
$ShellLauncherClass.SetDefaultShell("powershell -window minimized -command D:\uvs\WinPOS\run.bat", 0)
$ShellLauncherClass.SetEnabled($TRUE)`